# how to popup portfolio item in wordpress instead of opening in new window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using betheme WordPress theme there is no way to popup portfolio item in theme option. Yes i can popup thumbnail of my portfolio item but not portfolio details. I want to popup single portfolio item on click of thumbnail of that particular portfolio item.

here is the portfolio page code that contain the thumbnail of the all portfolio item.
can you suggest any alteration in below code achieve popup of portfolio item.

here is my site

> http://www.imgnxt.com/portfolio-types/jewellery/

I want to popup the portfolio-items here is the link which i want to popup

> http://www.imgnxt.com/portfolio-item/bariki/

The content of this page I want to popup. After clicking on thumbnail of previous link content.

Below is the code where the tumbnails appear on clicking 
 those thumbnail I want to popup the portfolio-items

```
 <?php
 /**
* The template for displaying content in the template-portfolio.php  template
*
* @package Betheme
* @author Muffin group
 * @link http://muffingroup.com
 */

  if( ! function_exists('mfn_content_portfolio') ){
  function mfn_content_portfolio( $query = false, $style = false ){
    global $wp_query;
    $output = '';

    $translate['readmore']      = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-readmore','Read more') : __('Read more','betheme');
    $translate['client']        = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-client','Client') : __('Client','betheme');
    $translate['date']          = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-date','Date') : __('Date','betheme');
    $translate['website']       = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-website','Website') : __('Website','betheme');
    $translate['view']          = mfn_opts_get('translate') ? mfn_opts_get('translate-view','View website') : __('View website','betheme');

    if( ! $query ) $query = $wp_query;
    if( ! $style ){
        if( $_GET && key_exists('mfn-p', $_GET) ){
            $style = $_GET['mfn-p']; // demo
        } else {
            $style = mfn_opts_get( 'portfolio-layout', 'grid' );
        }
    }

     if ( $query->have_posts() ){
        while ( $query->have_posts() ){
            $query->the_post();

            $item_class = array();
            $categories = '';

            $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'portfolio-types');
            if( is_array( $terms ) ){
                foreach( $terms as $term ){
                    $item_class[] = 'category-'. $term->slug;
                    $categories .= '<a href="'. site_url() .'/portfolio- types/'. $term->slug .'">'. $term->name .'</a>, ';
                }
                $categories = substr( $categories , 0, -2 );
            }
            $item_class[] = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-size', true );
            $item_class[] = has_post_thumbnail() ? 'has-thumbnail' : 'no-thumbnail';
            $item_class = implode(' ', $item_class);

            $external           = mfn_opts_get( 'portfolio-external' );
            $ext_link           = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-link', true );
            $large_image_url    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large' );


            // item backgrounds ---

            // style: list
            if( $item_bg_image = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-bg', true ) ){
                $item_bg_image = ' background-image:url('. $item_bg_image .');';
            }

            // style: masonry hover
            $item_bg_class = 'bg-'. mfn_brightness( mfn_opts_get( 'background-imageframe-link', '#2991d6' ), 169 );

            if( $item_bg_color = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-bg-hover', true ) ){

                $item_bg_class = 'bg-'. mfn_brightness( $item_bg_color, 169 );
                $item_bg_color = ' background-color:'. hex2rgba( $item_bg_color, 0.9 ) .';';

            }


            // Image Link ---------------------------------------------------------------------

            if( in_array( $external, array('disable','popup') ) ){

                // disable details & link popup 
                $link_before    = '<a class="link" href="'. $large_image_url[0] .'" rel="prettyphoto">';

            } elseif( $external && $ext_link ){

                // link to project website
                $link_before    = '<a class="link" href="'. $ext_link .'" target="'. $external .'">';

            } else {

                // link to project details
                $link_before    = '<a class="link" href="'. get_permalink() .'">';

            }


            // Echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

            $output .= '<li class="portfolio-item isotope-item '. $item_class .'">';


                if( $style == 'exposure' ){
                    // style: Exposure --------------------------------------------------------


                    $output .= $link_before;

                        // photo ------------------
                        $output .= '<div class="image-wrapper scale-with-grid">';
                            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'full', array( 'class'=>'scale-with-grid', 'itemprop'=>'image' ) );
                            $output .= '<div class="mask"></div>';
                        $output .= '</div>';

                        // title ------------------
                        $output .= '<div class="desc-inner">';
                            $output .= '<div class="section_wrapper">';
                                $output .= '<div class="desc-wrapper-inner">';

                                    $output .= '<div class="line"></div>';
                                    $output .= '<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">'. get_the_title() .'</h2>';

                                    $output .= '<div class="desc-wrappper">';
                                        $output .= get_the_excerpt();
                                    $output .= '</div>';

                                $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                        $output .= '</div>';

                    $output .= '</a>';


                    // details -------------------
                    $output .= '<div class="details-wrapper">';                 
                        $output .= '<div class="section_wrapper">';
                            $output .= '<div class="details-wrapper-inner">';

                                if( $link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-link', true ) ){
                                    $output .= '<div class="column one-fourth website">';
                                        $output .= '<h5 class="label">'. $translate['website'] .'</h5>';
                                        $output .= '<h5><a target="_blank" href="'. $link .'"><i class="icon-forward"></i>'. $translate['view'] .'</a></h5>';
                                    $output .= '</div>';
                                }

                                if( $client = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-client', true ) ){
                                    $output .= '<div class="column one-fourth client">';
                                        $output .= '<h5 class="label">'. $translate['client'] .'</h5>';
                                        $output .= '<h5>'. $client .'</h5>';
                                    $output .= '</div>';
                                }

                                $output .= '<div class="column one-fourth date">';
                                    $output .= '<h5 class="label">'. $translate['date'] .'</h5>';
                                    $output .= '<h5>'. get_the_date() .'</a></h5>';
                                $output .= '</div>';

                            $output .= '</div>';
                        $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';


                } elseif( $style == 'masonry-hover' ){
                    // style: Masonry Hover ---------------------------------------------------


                    $output .= '<div class="masonry-hover-wrapper">';   

                        // desc -------------------                     
                        $output .= '<div class="hover-desc '. $item_bg_class .'" style="'. $item_bg_color .'">';

                            $output .= '<div class="desc-inner">';

                                $output .= '<h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">'. $link_before . get_the_title() .'</a></h3>';
                                $output .= '<div class="desc-wrappper">';
                                    $output .= get_the_excerpt();
                                $output .= '</div>';

                            $output .= '</div>';

                            if( $external != 'disable' ){
                                $output .= '<div class="links-wrappper clearfix">';
                                    if( ! in_array( $external, array('_self','_blank') ) )  $output .= '<a class="zoom" href="'. $large_image_url[0] .'" rel="prettyphoto"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>';
                                    if( $ext_link ) $output .= '<a class="external" target="_blank" href="'. $ext_link .'" ><i class="icon-forward"></i></a>';
                                    if( ! $external )  $output .= $link_before. '<i class="icon-link"></i></a>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                            }

                        $output .= '</div>';

                        // photo ------------------
                        $output .= '<div class="image-wrapper scale-with-grid">';
                            $output .= $link_before;
                                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'full', array( 'class'=>'scale-with-grid', 'itemprop'=>'image' ) );
                            $output .= '</a>';
                        $output .= '</div>';

                    $output .= '</div>';


                } else {
                    // style: All -------------------------------------------------------------


                    $output .= '<div class="portfolio-item-fw-bg" style="'. $item_bg_color . $item_bg_image .'">';

                        $output .= '<div class="portfolio-item-fill"></div>';

                        if( $style == 'list' ) $output .= '<div class="section_wrapper">'; // style: List | Section Wrapper

                            // style: List | Desc ---------------------------------------------
                            $output .= '<div class="list_style_header">';
                                $output .= '<h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">'. $link_before . get_the_title() .'</a></h3>';
                                $output .= '<div class="links_wrapper">';
                                    $output .= '<a href="#" class="button button_js portfolio_prev_js"><span class="button_icon"><i class="icon-up-open"></i></span></a>';
                                    $output .= '<a href="#" class="button button_js portfolio_next_js"><span class="button_icon"><i class="icon-down-open"></i></span></a>';
                                    $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" class="button button_left button_theme button_js"><span class="button_icon"><i class="icon-link"></i></span><span class="button_label">'. $translate['readmore'] .'</span></a>';
                                $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';

                            // style: All | Photo ---------------------------------------------
                            $output .= '<div class="image_frame scale-with-grid">';
                                $output .= '<div class="image_wrapper">';       
                                    $output .= mfn_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio', $style );
                                $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';

                            // style: All | Desc ----------------------------------------------
                            $output .= '<div class="desc">';

                                $output .= '<div class="title_wrapper">';
                                    $output .= '<h5 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">'. $link_before . get_the_title() .'</a></h5>';                             
                                    $output .= '<div class="button-love">'. mfn_love() .'</div>';
                                $output .= '</div>';

                                $output .= '<div class="details-wrapper">';
                                    $output .= '<dl>';
                                        if( $client = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-client', true ) ){
                                            $output .= '<dt>'. $translate['client'] .'</dt>';
                                            $output .= '<dd>'. $client .'</dd>';
                                        }
                                        $output .= '<dt>'. $translate['date'] .'</dt>';
                                        $output .= '<dd>'. get_the_date() .'</dd>';
                                        if( $link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'mfn-post-link', true ) ){
                                            $output .= '<dt>'. $translate['website'] .'</dt>';
                                            $output .= '<dd><a target="_blank" href="'. $link .'"><i class="icon-forward"></i>'. $translate['view'] .'</a></dd>';
                                        }
                                    $output .= '</dl>';
                                $output .= '</div>';

                                $output .= '<div class="desc-wrapper">';
                                    $output .= get_the_excerpt();
                                $output .= '</div>';

                            $output .= '</div>';

                        if( $style == 'list' ) $output .= '</div>'; // style: List | end: Section Wrapper

                    $output .= '</div>';

                }


            $output .= '</li>';

        }
    }

    return $output;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Its already in your site. I can see a search icon on hovering and clicking on it, popup comes with the image. If you only need this, remove the title and link on hovering and keep only that search lens icon , may be in middle.

Comment: no that popups only thumbnail image...i want to popup content there in portfolio item page that appears on clicking thumbnail image.

Comment: i want to popup what comes after clicking in link icon or thumbnail image